# I can not select value from db

Tags: sql, vb.net

I want to get those data where done =0 in gridview

I wrote this query

```
select * from tbl where done=0
```

but I get every data from database

Comment: The query looks right, so you should show how you use it in the code. That's probably where the problem is.

Comment: Probably you have an error in the code that prepares and sends this sql text to your underlying database. It is necessary to show this code to get an answer. By the way, add a tag for the specific database you are using (sql is for generic sql Language)

Comment: what other `done` values are you getting in returned data?

Answer (score 1):

I have an example :

```
SELECT * FROM `bat` WHERE `b_runs`= 0;
```

Here maybe you have to change your datatype of your column.

It works with an `INT` datatype.

OR you can use :

```
SELECT * FROM `bat` WHERE `b_runs`LIKE '0' ;
```

Answer (score 1):

If I remember correctly; done is a reserved word.
Try the following:

```
  select * from tbl where [done]=0
```

Comment: For which database Language?

Comment: That would be the MS SQL. Indeed, I forgot to ask which dialect user1601363 was using.

Comment: No, I am pretty sure that 'done' is not a reserved keyword in T-SQL. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189822.aspx

Comment: I have been deceived :)